# Login screen logic with usercontrols

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Imagine we have a form and a couple of usercontrols.One of these user controls hadles the login operations, has username, pass textbox login button etc.When the program first opens up,it shows the form and within the form's load event,the usercontrol for the login screen pops up as:

```
login login = new login();
Controls.Add(login);
login.Show();
```

That is also no problem.Now,when the user enters the requested data and clicks ok button in the login control, login control must be closed and another usercontrol which is the main menu,must be shown in the form.How can I achieve that?
Tried adding the second user control as well,but seems very unlogical to me since the second user control must be shown based on the first user control (whether the user has logged in properly)

```
main main = new main();
Controls.Add(main);
main.Show();
```

So what is the best practice to handle these kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the login usercontrol, you can remove the control itself using the parent function - this will enable you to access the controls of where the usercontrols are placed (ie a panel).

From here you add the new mainmenu usercontrol, or in the load up of the main form you can stack the two usercontrols ontop of each other and bring the login control to the front. The former is probably best as it means you are creating controls as and when needed.

Edit:

As for best practice I'm not entirely sure on that, its probably whatever suits your programming needs. For instance, the panel which contains my usercontrols, I reference that right at the start of the program into a common class, so I can access it later on in different controls. This avoids having to cast back through parents.